# Android How to design Dpad layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to design dpad layout for remote control app. this layout should support multiple screen sizes.

I have followed this answer.but its not giving result that i want. 
[RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467849/custom-shape-button/36792997#36792997)

Please let me know what is the correct way that i should use.

[image]

Comment: Well its quite complicated. There is a library called [Radial menu](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android) for reference. Have a look at it if you already not.

Comment: Have you used this lib. I think its eclipse project and no guide.

Comment: Does it really matter ? Its android anyway . You can have a look at code and maybe you build your own by taking reference from it.

Comment: The project tutorial is on [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/radial-menu-widget/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki) . I also want to make a dpad layout. Firstly, I don't want this library feature "touch outside the circle dismiss automatically". Therefore, rather than it recommend `show()` and `dismiss()` the `RadialMenuWidget` view, I choose to add or remove this view directly on a ViewGroup but not mess with the popup window. Thankfully, it works without modify the library code.